# how to insert some html into a string's spot so i can find that text in a RichTextBox and replace it? - vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, string, open-source

I have this code attached to a button

```
 If htmlText.Contains("<frame src='demo.html'/>") Then
            htmlText = htmlText.Text.Replace("<frame src="demo.html/>", "<frame src='" & 
            OpenStory.FileName) 
 End If
```

and what i want it to do is find the "frame src='demo.html'/>" text in the hidden rhichtextbox which it's text is loaded from the OpenFileDialog and replace the 'demo.html' with the filename of the specified file from the OpenFileDialog.

I know that there's lots of errors and you can see them if you copy into vb but i can't figure it out. thanks heaps in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `htmlText` is a `RichTextBox` control, your code should be changed like this:

```
Dim findText As String = "<frame src='demo.html'/>"
Dim newText As String = "<frame src='" & OpenStory.FileName & "'/>"
htmlText.Text = htmlText.Text.Replace(findText, newText)
```

If `htmlText` is a string variable, your code should be changed like this:

```
Dim findText As String = "<frame src='demo.html'/>"
Dim newText As String = "<frame src='" & OpenStory.FileName & "'/>"
htmlText = htmlText.Replace(findText, newText)
```

Your posted code has issues because you are not matching the strings correctly.  You are testing for a string called 'demo.html' with single quotes but trying to change it by looking for "demo.html" with double quotes.

You are also trying to replace it with the OpenStory.FileName without a closing quote or closing bracket, which would mess up the existing HTML format.

As you can see from my answer, I can't figure out what `htmlText` is, because if it's a string, string's don't have a `Text` property, but a `RichTextBox` control does have `Text` property.  But then again, calling `Contains` on a `RichTextBox` makes it search for a *Control*, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you replace function should/could be...

```
htmlText = htmlText.Text.Replace("demo.html", OpenStory.FileName)
```

Don't think you need to replace the "frame src =".  It's present in both.  Just replacing the file name would be simpler.